# PHP nohup process is missing

Tags: php, linux, bash, unix, nohup

I launched background PHP process by nohup via SHH on my server. Server using Gentoo OS, Apache. PHP script always running, even when i close terminal. (always running cause it does some stuff that i can track in my application)
Here is `nohup` lanch

```
 nohup /usr/local/bin/php7-71LATEST-CLI /kunden/310040_81369/SalesTool/makeShedule.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Now i want to stop it. To do that i should to get ID of the process, but i cant find it. I tried different ways to get ID without success.
For example using `ps aux` process is not here:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
u310040  14175  0.0  0.7 438104 116748 ?       SNl  Jun27   1:08 /kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/var/my.cnf --basedir=/kund
u310040  28329  0.0  0.0   8692  5048 pts/1    SNs  13:13   0:00 -bash
u310040  28487  0.0  0.0   7964  3432 pts/1    RN+  15:41   0:00 ps aux
u310040  31280  0.0  0.0   6832  2908 ?        SN   May28   0:00 /bin/sh bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql_5.6.27/var/my.cnf --basedir=/kunden/310040_81369/ms_appl/mysql
```

also `top` command

```
 1702 u310040   25   5    8480   3940   3564 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
14175 u310040   28   8  438104 116748  10136 S   0.0  0.7   1:08.88 mysqld
28329 u310040   25   5    8692   5048   4540 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.17 bash
31280 u310040   28   8    6832   2908   2660 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 mysqld_safe
```

How i can stop it?

Note: i launched several times, so the script execute more than ones

Comment: How is the PHP script "always running"? A typical PHP script runs and ends, whether you run it on the background or otherwise. Are you running it in an infinite loop, or how's it working?

Comment: i`m running it using nohup. in the PHP script i have infinite loop, and it works on the background.